# Content management for my already coded website

Tags: php, html, css, authentication, content-management-system

I am in secondary school and learning web development and our latest school project was to come up with our own company based around a website.

Basically my website is going to display aspiring animator’s videos, there is going to be a place where other users of the website can comment feedback on these videos and there are going to be other resources for the animators to use.

I have already created the base of the website. I have placeholder youtube videos on the home screen (where the user’s videos would go) and I have a contact page and a resource page.

Basically, my teacher told me that if I wanted the website to actually function, that is to have a login system where users can go in and be able to post their own videos for the other users to see, (posting videos would most likely be in the form of submitting a youtube link, there the video would be displayed on the home page) and have a comment system for other users to be able to leave feedback on other user’s videos and so on, my best option was to use a CMS e.g. Drupal. I was unsure if this would be my best option, because as far as my research goes, I believe that CMS are made for users to use their web templates and it doesn’t work well for those who have already got a website coded. (unsure)

I am new to making websites but I am quite capable with a bit of learning. Basically, all I need to know is what method I should use to integrate this login system for users to be able to post and comment to my website and a way for an admin who would run the website to be able to manage the content on the website easily without having to change any of the code. Considering that I have already coded my website, I am unsure if this is possible and I do not have the time to start again.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: welcome to SO.. what have you tried so far? at least provide us with your plan of action or pseudocode

Comment: you should be able to create logins.. the only thing you would need to do is to check for sessions on every page. Research on sessions and login systems

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I belive that it would be lot easier to simply take your coded website and convert it to template for one of the most popular CMS platforms (Joomla, for example). It would allow you to use thousands of free plugins (also for video uploading and galleries, for that matter), and will make your site LOT safer. It's lot faster than coding your own CMS too - if design is not very complicated and you don't have lot of functions, I belive it would take you few days max to install Joomla, find, add and configure few necessary plugins, and follow one of hundreds of tutorials about converting your HTML to Joomla template.

If you insist on coding your own CMS, start with this tutorial
https://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/
It's old, from 2009, but it covers most of the basics of working with simple databases, user login sessions, etc.

Comment: Why downvote? I explained evertyhing that is bad for trying to make own CMS with so little knowledge, and even added link to tutorial if author decides to code it anyway.